# Is there a verb for slowly descending?

Tags: word-request

Is there a verb for slowly descending? For example, when a snowflake is slowly descending from the sky, is there a verb we can use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of possibilities. Both are from Merriam-Webster.

---

[**drift**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drift#h2):

> **1 a** : to become driven or carried along (as by a current of water, wind, or air)
>         // a balloon *drifting* in the wind
>   **2 b** : to move or float smoothly and effortlessly

So:

> The snowflake *drifted* down.

---

[**settle**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/settle):

> **2 a** : to sink gradually or to the bottom

So:

> The snowflake *settled* to the ground.

Comment: "Filtered down" has a connotation of slowness too.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty I wouldn't use *filtered* to talk about a falling snowflake though. Only some kind of liquid and for smaller distances.